# Loop to write a cimma separated list of items

Tags: c#, for-loop, separator

I need to write a for loop that prints 49 through 1, with each value separated by a comma. So, it must not print a comma after the last value.

I have this so far and have no clue , after an hour of research, what else to do.

```
For (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + ",");
}
```

Comment: 7 answers to a -3 question in 4 minutes. Wow!

Comment: @ThomasWeller When a question is super easy, people answer.  Even though we shouldn't.

Comment: @AgentWolf you can actually see where you are going wrong in terms of not truly keeping track of `i` if you use the debugger to step thru the code and have the console window opened up on another monitor or make room on your single monitor to see both the program .cs code and the console window you will be able to see the output realtime when stepping through the code..

Comment: I did not know how to keep tract of i. I am being forced to take a programming class for a networking major. I dropped out of CS a long time ago because programming never made any sense to me.

Comment: do a google search on 
[decrement loops](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for)

Comment: One-liner. `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 49).Reverse()));`

Comment: I fully understand decrement loops but when it came to the comma and it not appearing at the end, I had no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check where you are in your loop to know if you need to print the comma.

```
        public static void Test()
        {
            for (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + (i != 1 ? "," : ""));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.Join

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
for (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--) {
    numbers.Add(i.ToString());

}
string numberWithCommas = String.Join(",", numbers);
Console.WriteLine(numberWithCommas);
```

Or you can put in a if condition to check for the last element and conditionally print your comma.

The String.Join would be a neater way to do this operation. However as pointed out by @CommuSoft, if you are doing this operation for a large list of numbers, the memory used may be high in this operation.

Comment: A potential problem is the memory complexity. A large stream of output can for instance be written to a device. Perhaps you should mention this in your post...

Comment: @CommuSoft Added a note.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are at the last item, and don't write the comma in that case:

```
for (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--) {
    Console.Write(i);
    if (i > 1) {
        Console.Write(",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

(There are alternatives that are a little more elegant, but this is closest to your original code. You can for example write the comma before the number and skip the first comma.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
{
    Console.Write("{0}{1}", i, i == 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not keeping track of your value.

```
var content = String.Empty;
for(var i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
     content += (i + ",");

Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Once you have a value, then you apply it.  The problem your having is the scope never remains, it applies to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

The value of i determines when to add the comma:

```
For (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i >= 1 ? i + "," : i);
}
```